# Configure the Search Function in QGIS Web Client

Tags: qgis, qgis-web-client

I have set up the QGIS Web Client but do not know how to get the search function to work. I read the instructions in the guide but can't really understand what it is saying:

```
 6.1.2. PHP configuration file
    =============================

Configuration for the services is stored in  `config.php`.

Example:

  /****************************
   * Map rewrite configuration
   */
  // Prefix map name with path
  #define('MAP_PATH_REWRITE', '/home/xxx/public_html/QGIS-Web-Client/projects/');
  // Append .qgs to the map name
  #define('MAP_PATH_APPEND_QGS', true);


  /**************************************
   * search configuration
   */
  // Configuration for searchable layers
  $searchlayers_config = array(
      // Key is layer name
      'Country' => array(
          // SQL for text search: where to search
          'search_column' => 'name'
      )
  );

  // Default search tables
  define('DEFAULT_SEARCH_LAYERS', 'Country');
  // Limit search results
  define('SEARCH_LIMIT', 100);


  /**************************************
   *  Get legend configuration
   */
  // Cache expiry time in seconds 0=never cache
  define('GET_LEGEND_CACHE_EXPIRY', 60*60);
  // Cache directory, defaults to dirname(__FILE__) . '/legend_cache'
  define('GET_LEGEND_CACHE_DIRECTORY', null);
  // Defaults to current URL + '../cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?'
  define('WMS_ONLINE_RESOURCE', null);

  /* End configuration */

QGIS Web Client needs to know where to find the scripts, since most
configuration is read from the project file, this must be passed in the
query string, the file where this parameters are set is
GlobalOptions.js see the example below:

  // Adds project_map, read value from query string
  var project_map = Ext.urlDecode(window.location.search.substring(1)).map;

  var searchBoxQueryURL = '../php/search.php?map=' + project_map;
  var searchBoxGetGeomURL = '../php/search_geom.php?map=' + project_map;
```

Can anyone enlighten me what must I do, which part of the code to edit? Thanks.